# c++ readfile with varying element amounts per line?

Tags: c++, readfile

if I have a file like this, say called file.txt

```
20  
25  97
97  5
```

How would i properly read it given that the second column has missing the second element in the first row?I attempted this

```
int main()
{

    ifstream readFile;
    string filename;
    cout << "Please enter file name and extention: " << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    readFile.open(filename);

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

    while (readFile >> row >> column)
    {
//does something
}
```

However I get segmenation fault

Comment: Depends completely on what you mean by properly. What do you expect to happen when one of the numbers is missing?

Answer (score 3):

I would like using [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) to read lines and [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) to parse the lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(void) {
    std::string filename;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream readFile;
    std::cout << "Please enter file name and extention: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> filename;
    readFile.open(filename);
    if (!readFile) {
        std::cout << "open error\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (std::getline(readFile, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        int row = 0, column = 0;
        if (ss >> row >> column) {
            std::cout << "row = " << row << ", column = " << column << '\n';
        } else {
            std::cout << "invalid line\n";
        }
    }

    readFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Another version (also print partial line):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(void) {
    std::string filename;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream readFile;
    std::cout << "Please enter file name and extention: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> filename;
    readFile.open(filename);
    if (!readFile) {
        std::cout << "open error\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (std::getline(readFile, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        int row = 0, column = 0;
        bool row_valid = false, column_valid = false;
        if (ss >> row) row_valid = true;
        if (ss >> column) column_valid = true;
        std::cout << "row = ";
        if (row_valid) std::cout << row; else std::cout << "(none)";
        std::cout << ", column = ";
        if (column_valid) std::cout << column; else std::cout << "(none)";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    readFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Yet another version (support lines with 3 integers and more):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::string filename;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream readFile;
    std::cout << "Please enter file name and extention: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> filename;
    readFile.open(filename);
    if (!readFile) {
        std::cout << "open error\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (std::getline(readFile, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::vector<int> lineInts;
        int data;
        while (ss >> data) lineInts.push_back(data);
        std::cout << lineInts.size() << " elements:";
        for (int d : lineInts) std::cout << ' ' << d;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    readFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if i still wanted to read the invalid line? Say row = 20 column = empty

Comment: @davidlingg2000 Added that version.